# tocloft: How to add chapters in a new list defined with \newlistof?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Using the `tocloft` package, I defined a "List of Footnotes" which is displayed as a simple list, while I would like to display the chapters, too, in the following way:

```
List of Figures
                        (page)% not to be displayed
1 Chapter Title           1   % to be displayed like a chapter in the ToC of standard classes
  1 Text of footnote      2
2 Chapter Title           3
  1 Text of footnote      4
  2 Text of footnote      5
```

Here is what I tried. (The strings of code I commented out and described as "1st try" and "2nd try" are what I tried, but they do not work.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newcommand\footnotesname{List of Footnotes}
\newlistof[chapter]{FootnoteQuote}{loq}{\footnotesname}% FootnoteQuote is a new counter for the footnotes
\LetLtxMacro{\oldfootnote}{\footnote}
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
  \oldfootnote{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{FootnoteQuote}%
  \addcontentsline{loq}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theFootnoteQuote}#1}% formatted as sections
}
\renewcommand\theFootnoteQuote{\arabic{FootnoteQuote}}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}% No dotted leader lines
\let\oldlistofFootnoteQuote\listofFootnoteQuote% To add an entry in the ToC
\renewcommand\listofFootnoteQuote{%
  \oldlistofFootnoteQuote%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\footnotesname}\par%
}
% \LetLtxMacro{\oldchapter}{\chapter}% 1st try
% \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
%   \oldchapter{#1}%
%   \addcontentsline{loq}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}% taken from report.cls
% }
%
% \usepackage{etoolbox}% 2nd try
% \preto\chapter{\addtocontents{loq}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}

\begin{document}

% \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
Some words Some words Some words Some words\footnote{A footnote.} Some words Some words

\chapter{Two}
Some words Some words Some words Some words\footnote{A footnote.} Some words Some words

Some words Some words Some words Some words\footnote{A footnote.} Some words Some words

Some words Some words Some words Some words\footnote{A footnote.} Some words Some words

\listofFootnoteQuote

\end{document}
```

*Additional Info:* I am working with the `scrreprt` class, but I would be very glad if it could work also with the standard LaTeX classes.

Comment: This is similar to a question, I answered recently: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200360/list-of-tables-or-figures-by-section-latex/200385#200385, although not with `tocloft` then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I've patched `\@@makechapterhead` which sets the actual chapter heading in [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). The final heading-related "construction" is to insert a vertical skip called `\chapterheadendvskip`. So, we add to that macro an `\addcontentsline` submission:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{letltxmacro,etoolbox}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newcommand\footnotesname{List of Footnotes}
\newlistof[chapter]{FootnoteQuote}{loq}{\footnotesname}% FootnoteQuote is a new counter for the footnotes
\LetLtxMacro{\oldfootnote}{\footnote}
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
  \oldfootnote{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{FootnoteQuote}%
  \addcontentsline{loq}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theFootnoteQuote}#1}% formatted as sections
}
\renewcommand\theFootnoteQuote{\arabic{FootnoteQuote}}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}% No dotted leader lines
\let\oldlistofFootnoteQuote\listofFootnoteQuote% To add an entry in the ToC
\renewcommand\listofFootnoteQuote{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\footnotesname}\par%
  \oldlistofFootnoteQuote%
}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\chapterheadendvskip}% <search>
  {\chapterheadendvskip%
   \addcontentsline{loq}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}% Replace
  {}{}% <successs><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
Some words Some words Some words Some words\footnote{A footnote.} Some words Some words

\chapter{Two}
Some words Some words Some words Some words\footnote{A footnote.} Some words Some words

Some words Some words Some words Some words\footnote{A footnote.} Some words Some words

Some words Some words Some words Some words\footnote{A footnote.} Some words Some words

\listofFootnoteQuote

\end{document}
```

Note that the above patch will insert a chapter-style heading in the List of Footnotes even if the chapter has no footnotes. Also, I've updated you definition of `\listofFootnoteQuote` to avoid problems when it spans more than one page.

Comment: Thanks! I have a question: will this work also if I use `titlesec` to change the appearance of the chapter-head? (I know this question might be too generic, but I have already tried to modify `\@makechapterhead` and the solution you propose doesn't work anymore.)

Comment: @PierPaolo: No, since [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) uses a different set of macros to construct the titles. While the patch may work, `\@@makechapterhead` is never executed. One would possibly follow the same procedure as I did to identify the macro executed around the end of the `\chapter` setting (which might be intricate when dealing with `titlesec`) and patch that.