# List of figure modified style

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

How can I change the style of list of figure to make it equal to table of contents as shown in the picture below ? I'm using `\documentclass{article}` and creating list of figure with code `\listoffigure` .

[image]

Comment: The `tocloft` package should be a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The look of a `lof` like the `toc` can be achieved via the `\cftfig....` macros from `tocloft` package. Basically this requires only two of those commands:

- `\cftfigindent` -- the indentation of figure entries
- `\cftfigfont` -- the font specification

If the `lof` should be splitted in sections, please have a look on this answer of mine:
[List of tables (or figures) by section - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200360/list-of-tables-or-figures-by-section-latex/200385#200385)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{tocloft}


\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\section{First -- with no pagebreak}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummyfigure 1}
\end{figure}

\section{Second with pagebreak}%

\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummyfigure 2}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is work friend but after I used `\usepackage{tocloft}` the size and type of font of my title have changed too. The name 'Sumário' and 'lista de figuras' are so big now. What can I do to solve this ?

Comment: @Freitas: You did not provide any document to work with ... It's hard to guess where I should set the fontsize change

Comment: And one more question. You use `\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0pt}` to config the list of figure, so how can I do the same thing to config the list of tables ? Thx for your help =)

Comment: `\renewcommand{\cfttabindent}{0pt}`, see the corresponding section 2.3 of the `tocloft` manual please

Comment: I'm learning now how to work with Latex, so my code is very messy and confusing. But I will try to identify where I am setting the size of the table of contents font and I will study the manual. Thx for your help =)