# splitting list of figures into parts

Tags: floats

I want to split the list of figures in my report into two parts as shown below. In part 1 I have chapters from 1 to 5. Similarly in part 2.

```
                            **LIST OF FIGURES**
```

PART I

1.1 figure1. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  2

3.1 figure2. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  10

5.1 figure3. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  17

5.2 figure4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  20

PART II

1.1 figure5. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22

3.1 figure6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  38

5.1 figure7. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  40

5.2 figure8. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  44

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I answered a similar question some time ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200360/list-of-tables-or-figures-by-section-latex

Comment: Information about the document class you're using is essential.

Comment: The `titlesec` package has a `titletoc` component, which defines `\startlist, \stoplist, \resumelist` and `\printlist` commands that are done for that.